The distribution of $XY+(1-X)(1-Y)$ for $X,Y$ sampled uniformly from [0,1]
Let $X,Y$ be sampled uniformly from the interval $[0,1]$ and $Z=XY+(1-X)(1-Y)$. I would like to know the exact distribution of $Z$. I conjecture it should be uniform as well, but was not able to prove or refute the conjecture.
An interpretation of $Z$ is the area of two rectangles determined by points $\{(0,0),(X,Y)\}$ and $\{(X,Y),(1,1)\}$ for $(X,Y)$ chosen uniformly from a unit square. It's not clear to me whether this interpretation helps to find the exact distribution of $Z$.

Please edit to include your efforts.  Uniformity ought to be easy to test.

As suggested in the comments, perform the transformation $$X = U + 1/2, \quad Y = V + 1/2$$ to obtain
$$Z = XY + (1-X)(1-Y) = 2UV + 1/2, \\
U, V \sim \operatorname{Uniform}(-1/2,1/2). \tag{1}$$
This suggests $Z - 1/2$ is symmetric about $0$.  Specifically, if $U$ and $V$ share the same sign, then $UV$ is positive; if they have opposite signs, then $UV$ is negative; and because each sign parity is equiprobable, we may simplify the calculation by momentarily assuming that $U, V > 0$ and computing the density of $Z$ for this case, then reflecting the density across the line $Z = 1/2$.
To this end, consider the variable $4UV = U_1 U_2$, where $U_1, U_2$ are iid uniform on $(0,1)$.  Then $\log 4UV = \log U_1 + \log U_2$, and since the negative logarithm of a uniform distributed random variable on $(0,1)$ yields an exponentially distributed random variable with mean $1$, i.e.
$$-\log U_1 \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(1), \\
f_{-\log U_1}(u) = f_U(e^{-u}) \left|\frac{d}{du}[e^{-u}]\right| = e^{-u}, \tag{2}$$
and the sum of two iid exponential random variables is gamma with shape $2$, we have
$$W = -\log 4UV \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(2,1), \\
f_{W}(w) =  we^{-w}, \quad w > 0. \tag{3}$$
Since
$$Z = \frac{1 + e^{-W}}{2}, \tag{4}$$
and this transformation is one-to-one, we obtain
$$\begin{align}
f_Z(z) &= f_W\left(-\log(2z-1)\right) \left|\frac{d}{dz}\left[-\log (2z-1)\right]\right| \\
&= (-\log (2z-1))e^{\log(2z-1)} \cdot \frac{2}{2z-1} \\
&= -\log (2z-1), \quad 1/2 < z < 1. \tag{5}
\end{align}$$
Therefore, the full PDF of $Z$ is
$$f_Z(z) = \begin{cases} -\log(1-2z), & 0 < z < 1/2 \\ -\log(2z-1), & 1/2 < z < 1 \end{cases} = -\log |2z-1|,$$ for $0 < z < 1$ and $z \ne 1/2$.

Let me include my effort as an answer. The distribution of $Z$ is not uniform over $[0,1]$. First we can calculate the moments:
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Z^r] = \sum_{k=0}^r \binom{r}{k} \mathbb E[X^k(1-X)^{r-k}]^2.
\end{align}
For uniform $X\in[0,1]$, the expectation $\mathbb E[X^k(1-X)^{r-k}]^2=B(k+1,r-k+1)=\frac{1}{r+1}\binom{r}{k}^{-1}$, where $B$ is the beta function.
This implies that the moment
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Z^r] = \frac{1}{(r+1)^2}\sum_{k=0}^r \binom{r}{k}^{-1} =\frac{2+\Theta(1/r)}{(r+1)^2}.
\end{align}
If $Z$ were uniform, the moments would be $\mathbb E[Z^r]=B(r+1,1)=\frac{1}{r+1}$. Clearly they are different.
The random variable $Z$ does not look like a beta random variable to me either because I don't know how to write the moments as a beta function. An interesting question arises from here: for what $\alpha,\beta$, if $X,Y\sim\mathrm{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ then $Z$ is beta distributed? I'd appreciate and accept an answer if anyone can share how to find the parameters $\alpha,\beta$.

Regarding your question about whether $Z$ can ever be beta distributed, I don't have an analytic solution, but numerical simulation strongly suggests that the answer is no.  There is no choice of shape parameters for $X, Y$ iid beta variables that makes $Z$ also beta.
